# How to use browser GeoLocation after user allows access

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I'm having trouble with a weather API call which returns JSON based on geoLocation. The browser asks the question allow/deny access to location and then I want the API call to happen, preferably on page load. I have put the call behind a button click instead but it still doesn't update the page with the local weather. However, if I step through the code using the debugger it works properly.

Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var curLatitude = 'x';
    var curLongditude = 'y';
    var weatherApi = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,GB&APPID=[insert-registered-api-key]';

// check for Geolocation support
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            curLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
            curLongditude = position.coords.longitude;
                if (curLatitude !== 'x' && curLongditude !== 'y') {
                    weatherApi = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + curLatitude + 
                                        '&lon=' + curLongditude + '&APPID=[insert-registered-api-key]';

                };
            loadWeather(weatherApi);
            }, function() {                     
                console.log('FAILED');
                } );
    } else { 
            console.log('No geoLoc');
            // no geo location support - just load London weather
            loadWeather(weatherApi);
    };


    $('#btnLocal').click(function () {
        $(".message").html('clicked');
        loadWeather(weatherApi);
    });

    function loadWeather(weatherApiUri) {


        var current = "";
        var ok;


        var ret = $.getJSON(weatherApiUri, function(jsonres) {
            console.log( "JSON Data: loaded" );
            current = 'called api';
            console.log(current);               

            $(".message").html(current);
        }).done(function() {
             console.log( "done" );
          }).fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
          }).always(function() {
            console.log( "complete" );
          });




            var weatherReturned = {id:0 , main:"weather", description:"weather detail", icon:"code" };
            weatherReturned = ret.responseJSON.weather;
            $(".message").html(ret.responseJSON.name + ', ' + weatherReturned[0].description);

    };

});
```

JSON response:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon"
:"10d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":290.673,"pressure":1009.48,"humidity":83,"temp_min":290
.673,"temp_max":290.673,"sea_level":1019.21,"grnd_level":1009.48},"wind":{"speed":4.3,"deg":93.0027}
,"rain":{"3h":0.1375},"clouds":{"all":92},"dt":1462884891,"sys":{"message":0.0043,"country":"GB","sunrise"
:1462853704,"sunset":1462909185},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

Comment: What if you provide a timeout option in getCurrentPostion, like this navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {/*success*/}, function(){/*fail*/}, {timeout:5000});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to set a timer with call setInterval function.

In timer function you can check a flag you will set after **navigator.geolocation** check pass.

Only in interval function you will put the logic.

Just don't forget to clear timer to avoid unwanted calls.

Code can be like this:

```
 var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(geoReady){
      // clear interval
      window.clearInterval(timer);

      // do your logic
    }, 300
 }

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
     geoReady = true;
 }
 else {
   // clear interval
      window.clearInterval(timer);

 }
```

Comment: I ended up using the IP address for location but I'm sure this code will work. Thanks.